# console.time() on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, time, safari, console

I am trying to optimize a web app for iPad (iOS 5.1.1) and I was wondering **how to measure the time spent on a function**.

On the desktop there is **console.time() and console.timeEnd()** for both firebug and webkit's console. Unfortunately I cannot make it work **on iOS**, only console.log() seems to be supported.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

// ....

var end = new Date().getTime();

console.log(end-start);
```

Comment: Indeed it seems to match firebug's API with a few milliseconds more, it will do the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Based on **xdazz** answer I tried to replace the two functions in order for it to **work on iOS without refactoring** all timers :

```
if(!console){var console = {};} // for those without a console - mind the context
console.timers = {};
console.time = function(timer)
{
    if(!timer){timer="Timer";}
    console.timers[timer] = new Date().getTime();
};
console.timeEnd = function(timer)
{
    if(!timer){timer="Timer";}
    console.log(timer+": "+(new Date().getTime()-console.timers[timer]));
};
```

**Warning**: Doing so will replace the original API and therefore might provide less accurate data on your desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As of an iPhone 4 CDMA running iOS 6, mobile Safari supports `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()`.